# magento catalog sorting

Tags: magento

In magento we can sort catalog by price. I have some products which have price = zero (that means that we callback to customer or customer calling us to check price with us)

Is there any way to sort by price (from lower to bigger) in such way, that products with zero price will bein the end of the list???

I think that for such solution I must add some additional conditions to product collection model and join this zero price items to the end of collection, but I don't know how to do this.

May be someone knows how, or knows another solution

thanx

Answer (score 0):

go to Mage_Catalog_Model_Category and around 262 line, function: getProductCollection modifiy the code to something like that:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this)
        ->addAttributeToSort('price', 'desc');
    return $collection;
}
```

And you can get more info about collections on this url http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento gl

Comment: In that way products with zero price would be first, and I need them to be last. Also this filter will not work with filters (Layer)